# collection view reloading before fetching from api

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, alamofire

I have a collection view which reloads once the data is fetched from the api.
I have condition that when a array count is greater than zero,it should reload the collection view.
The code is as given below:

```
if self.mainarray.count>0
                                {
                                    self.collectionview1.reloadData()
                                }
```

If the mainarray count is 2,then it is reloading the collection view when the count is 1 itself.
How to make it reload only when the full data is fetched?

```
func getcart() {

        print("getcart function",self.token)

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                            "Content-Type":"application/json",
                            "Authorization":"Bearer "+self.token!
                        ]

                   AF.request("https:XXXX", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

                      switch response.result {
                                 case .success(let json):
                             // print("Validation Successful",json)

                             if let res = json as? [[String: Any]]{

                                print("res count is",res.count)

                                self.skuarray.removeAll()

                                for item in 0..<res.count
                                {

                                    self.sku = res[item]["name"] as! String
                                    self.skuarray.append(self.sku!)
                                    let qty:Double = res[item]["qty"] as! Double

                                }

                                if self.skuarray.count > 0
                                {
                                    for i in 0..<self.skuarray.count
                                    {
                                        self.getimage(sku:self.skuarray[i])
                                    }
                                }

                              }
                        else
                             {
                                self.showAlert(message: "No products in the cart")
                             }

                        case let .failure(error):
                              print(error)
                          }

                  }

              }



    func getimage(sku: String)
    {

        AF.request("https:XXXXXX" + sku, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

                      //New
                      let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                      do {


                          let user = try decoder.decode(ProductDetailDataModel.self, from: response.data!)
                           self.detailmodel = user
                          // self.orgsearchDataModel = user
                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                                self.doLabelChange()
                                print("total images aree",self.mainarray)
                                if !self.mainarray.isEmpty
                                {
                                    self.tableview1.reloadData()
                                }
                            }



                      } catch {
                          print(error.localizedDescription)
                      }

                    }

    }


 func doLabelChange(){



            let sku = UserDefaults.standard.set((self.detailmodel?.sku)!, forKey: "sku")

            let array = self.detailmodel?.mediaGalleryEntries

            print("array is",array)


                let image = array![0].file
                print("image is ",image)

            let imageurl = "https://adamas-intl.com/pub/media/catalog/product/" + image

            print("imageurl is",imageurl)

            self.mainarray.append(imageurl)

        }
```

Comment: Where is your API call for the fetch? Is it an async concept issue? Or a multiple async calls issue (where a dispatchgroup might help). Also, prefers `!aaa.isEmpty` over `aaa.count > 0`.

Comment: yes it is multiple api calls.i call one api first and the value from this api is looped in another api,then fetched this mainarray.So when this mainarray count is more then it should reload the collection view

Comment: Api is looped? Could you show your code?

Comment: yes it is looped.

Comment: please post your full class code or share demo project ...

Comment: have posted the code in the question

Comment: @Saranya You have to add `completionHandler` as these are `Asynchronous` requests. A google search will help you a lot with it.

Comment: It already is written within  DispatchQueue.main.async {}.So what could be the issue?

Comment: Consider using `DispatchGroup` . See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)